# Multiple Async/Await Try-Catch Block

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I am here because i am having troubles debugging my app. It's very annoying not see why my app crashes. I was using promises (with then/catch blocks) but i get on the necessity of using async/await.

I have a method where i do multiple await on it. The problem here is that if my app crashes because any reason i never know whats the problem on it. I have described the block like this:

```
         static async processCSGOGroupsAndUsers (groupName)  {

    try{
        const csgoApiData = await csgoApi(groupName);

        const parsedData = await xmltojson(csgoApiData);

        const id = parsedData.memberList.groupID64;
        //const members = await retrieveMembers(groupName, parsedData.memberList.memberCount);
        const totalUsers = await UsersService.processCSGOUsers(id, parsedData);

        const csgoGroup = {
            name: parsedData.memberList.groupDetails.groupName,
            siteUrl: parsedData.memberList.groupDetails.groupURL,
            id,
            totalUsers
        };

        await GroupsDao.save(csgoGroup);

    }catch (err){
        return err;
    }

}


  static async processCSGOUsers (groupId, parsedData) {

    try{

        let steamIdsArr = [];

        const usersSteamIdsObj = parsedData.memberList.members.steamID64;

        Object.keys(usersSteamIdsObj).forEach(key => {
            //if (steamIdsArr.length < 2)  // TODO csGOBackPackAPI don't let me do more than 50 request per hour
                steamIdsArr.push({
                    steam_group_id_64: groupId,
                    steam_id_64: usersSteamIdsObj[key]
                });
        });

        //const filteredUsers =  await UserService.filterUsersByInventoryValue(steamIdsArr);
        UsersDao.saveUsers(steamIdsArr);

    }   catch(err){

        console.log(err);

        return err;
    }
}

static processCSGOGroups(req, res){
    GroupService
        .processCSGOGroupsAndUsers(req.body.group)
        .then( () => res.status(200).end())
        .catch( error => res.status(400).send(error));

}
```

Is there a better approach than mine's?

Comment: "*i get on the necessity of using async/await.*" - what? There's no necessity at all. If you have working code that uses promise methods, why change it?

Comment: You definitely don't want to `return err`, that simply ignoring it and treating it as a successful result value instead. If you are not trying to handle any errors, why do you use `try`/`catch` at all?

Comment: I started using async/await because need to operate with high level scope variables. Yes, i want to handle errors as you see on the code i am making external api calls, database operations

Comment: Well, so *how* do you want to handle them? The code you've shown doesn't do anything (except one log) when something fails.

Comment: I encapsulate my business logic on a service. This service is being called by a high level controller. So, it would be perfect if i could throw (like Java) the error to the controller (so i can answer with a 400 status code + the error).

Comment: As I said, for that you must not `catch` and `return` it. `throw` it instead, or just don't catch it in the first place so that the exception simply bubbles.

Comment: change the catch block from `} catch (err) { return err; }` to `} catch (err) { console.log(err) }`. or `throw new Error(err)`. The return keyword is used inside functions to return a value. You cannot use `return` in that manner. To see what is happening when that error code runs, open a new file and put inside it `return 'ok i see now'` and then run it.

Answer (score 0):

I created an NPM package to help with situations like this.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@simmo/task

The following shows example usage. The idea is that it should help remove try/catch replacing with conditional logic - hopefully helping to make everything a little more readable! :)

```
import task from '@simmo/task'

const { error, data } = await task(fetch('/some-api'))

if (error) {
  // Failure
  console.error(error)
} else {
  // Success
  console.log(data)
}
```